# Exporting settings in a code with Features / Strongarm - how to detect right variables - config ones

Tags: features, strongarm

Many modules does not support Features, so I need Strongarm module to export config in the code. But in situation where i have many contrib modules, it seems tedious work. not all variables are named after module.

More important, how can I know which variables are used for settings, as I noticed some vars are not used for settings but may be user/module specific, and I need to aviod them.

I want to Strongarm only variables that have to do something with the config.

Is it done by researching modules one by one ? What are your experiences (It would be nice if I could filter variables that are used only in config :) )

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the Drupal variables table doesn't provide any distinction between **variables used for configuration** (e.g., whether anonymous pages should be cached) and **variables used to store transient values** (e.g., date cron was last run, which tabs are currently active in the UI), so there's no automatic way to do this.  *(Fortunately, it looks like Drupal 8's configuration management system will handle this better.)*

I typically export and update Features modules from the command line using Drush.  I've been using the following **Unix shell script** to list Features Components which haven't yet been exported to any feature — the script **filters out Features Components I know I don't want in my Features modules**:

```
drush fc % --not-exported \
    | grep -v '^ dependencies:' \
    | grep -v '^ user_permission:access devel information' \
    | grep -v '^ user_permission:execute php code' \
    | grep -v '^ user_permission:switch users' \
    | grep -v '^ uuid_node:' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:additional_settings__active_tab_' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:cron_key' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:cron_last' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:ctools_last_cron' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:date_api_version' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:dev_mem' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:dev_timer' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_api_url' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_error_handlers' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_execution' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_krumo_skin' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_page_alter' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_query_display' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_query_sort' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_raw_names' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_rebuild_theme_registry' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_redirect_page' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_use_uncompressed_jquery' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_xhprof_directory' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_xhprof_enabled' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:devel_xhprof_url' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:drupal_css_cache_files' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:drupal_http_request_fails' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:drupal_js_cache_files' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:drupal_private_key' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:entityreference:base-tables' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:features_codecache' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:features_ignored_orphans' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:features_semaphore' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:install_profile' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:install_task' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:install_time' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:mimemail_key' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:prod_check_module_list_lastrun' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:simplenews_last_cron' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:simplenews_last_sent' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:simplenews_private_key' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:simplenews_source_cache' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:update_last_check' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:xmlsitemap_generated_last' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:xmlsitemap_rebuild_needed' \
    | grep -v '^ variable:xmlsitemap_regenerate_needed'
```

Comment: There is some effort to do this better way also for Drupal7: http://drupal.org/project/configuration . It looks promising. As for your answer, you suggest that I must manually discover what variables are transient and exclude them this way ? This could be tedious with many contributed modules installed, but probably unavoidable :( . Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I haven't found a better way than to manually examine each variable individually, then add it to my blacklist.

Comment: Oh my. I think then it is best approach, when I need to change config of unsupported contrib modules on dev, to research which vars are right, and add them to feature. Doing all this for +50 contrib modules would take me days, and probably most of them wont be changed (in settings)

Comment: There has been some effort to simplify this, but I do not see it is maintainted/developed recently http://drupal.org/project/selector

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2400531 gives a list of features components that should never be exported, and mentions the Features Banish module as a way to prevent accidentally exporting them.